# Error while getting sql record using EntityManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am using `EntityManager` in spring boot app to get result from this query

```
select (c.data::jsonb)->>'employee_Id' as empId from employee e where e.dept ='employee' and  (e.data::jsonb)->>'section_id' = '1235'
```

Its giving me correct output in `PgAdmin` but in java code
 `List resultList = em.createNativeQuery(str).setParameter(1, sectionId ).getResultList();`

Giving error ERROR: `syntax error at or near ":"` its breaking at `data::jsonb` .How do handle this using `EntityManager`.

Comment: I guess you are casting c.data to jsonb but it is mentioned employeeId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `CAST` like `CAST(c.data as jsonb)->>'product_id'` from `string` to `JSONB`. However i would highly suggest that you don't use `TEXT` for your `JSON` type data.

```
 ALTER TABLE employee ALTER COLUMN data TYPE JSON USING data::JSON;
```

`